# Include title and author, and organizing logos in Latex

Tags: logos

I am a beginner in Latex trying to organize the logos on my article document. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[headsepline]{article} 

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\begin{document}  

\setlength{\headheight}{5pt} 
\ihead{\includegraphics[width=4\baselineskip]{jpgfile}
\begin{tabular}[b]{l}{\huge A very long Institute name} 
\\ Address of the institution 
\end{tabular} } 

\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Introduction}
\setlength{\headheight}{5pt} 
\ofoot{\includegraphics[width=2\baselineskip]{jpgfile}
\begin{tabular}[b]{l}{\huge A very long Institute name} 
\\ Address of the institution 
\end{tabular} } 

\newpage
\section{Introduction}

\setlength{\headheight}{5pt} 
\ofoot{\includegraphics[width=2\baselineskip]{jpgfile}
\begin{tabular}[b]{l}{\huge A very long Institute name} 
\\ Address of the institution 
\end{tabular} } 


\newpage
\section{Introduction}

\setlength{\headheight}{5pt} 
\ofoot{\includegraphics[width=2\baselineskip]{jpgfile}
\begin{tabular}[b]{l}{\huge A very long Institute name} 
\\ Address of the institution 
\end{tabular} } 


\end{document}
```

So, I was able to include at the top of first page my logo. Now I want to put this logo only on the bottom left from page 2 till the end.

Also, I want to include the title, the author and a date below the logo on the first page.

Any help guys?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refine the title page, e.g. modifying maketitle:

```
\documentclass[headsepline]{article} 

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\author{The Author}
\title{The Really Long Title}
\date{\today}

% Define titlepage
\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{%
    \setlength{\headheight}{5pt} 
    \ihead{\includegraphics[width=4\baselineskip]{jpgfile}
        \begin{tabular}[b]{l}{\huge A very long Institute name} 
        \\ Address of the institution 
    \end{tabular} } 
    \ofoot{}
    \@maketitle%
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \ihead{}
    %\setlength{\headheight}{5pt} 
    \ofoot{\includegraphics[width=2\baselineskip]{jpgfile}
    \begin{tabular}[b]{l}{\huge A very long Institute name} 
    \\ Address of the institution 
    \end{tabular}}%
}

\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother

\begin{document}  
  \maketitle
 %%%\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\newpage
\section{Introduction}

\newpage
\section{Introduction}

\newpage
\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I change the position of the tittle lower/to the left and etc? `\author{The Author} \title{The Really Long Title} \date{\today}` this part.

Comment: @Laura you need to modify the \@maketitle command, e.g. changing the vertical shift \vskip 1.5em to a larger one (for lower text) or to replace center by something else if you want the author further to the left